# Serving static site on Google cloud storage doesn't return my index

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket set as public and can access all my `/index.html` 
 and `/dir/index.html` pages.
[Have assigned the landing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#optional_assigning_pages) on the bucket web site properties.
I am the verified own of the domain using google webmaster page.
Still, when try to access https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/ I receive only the bucket list results not the the assigned index page.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/ address is simply browsing your bucket's content with the regular GCS browser application. The behaviour is the expected one.

To access your website you need to use the `http://my-bucket` address (or `https://my-bucket` if you did [set it up for HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https)). This assumes you correctly [created the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#create-bucket) and `my-bucket` matches your domain.

See also the [Website configuration examples](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#examples)

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid to point the DNS to it before know if it was working. After point the CNAME to my bucket everything worked.